Why is a non-partitioned table with composite indexing performing better than a partitioned table?
I have a table A with around 300 million rows, where 2 million rows are inserted daily. The table A is partitioned by the MONTH_ID column, with each partition corresponding to a month, and has an index on the DATE column (I created an index within each partition).
CREATE TABLE Table_A (
    "TXN_REFR_NBR" VARCHAR2(100),
    "TXN_REFR_NBR_HANDLE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "BRANCH_CODE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "GRAND_BRANCH_LV2" VARCHAR2(50),
    "GRAND_BRANCH_LV1" VARCHAR2(50),
    "BRANCH_QLBC" VARCHAR2(50),
    "CCY" VARCHAR2(15),
    "TXN_DATE" DATE,
    "VALUE_DATE" DATE,
    "GL_CODE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "GL_NAME" VARCHAR2(100),
    "GL_CODE_NBR_HANDLE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "GL_NAME_HANDLE" VARCHAR2(200),
    "PL_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(100),
    "DB_FCYAMOUNT" NUMBER,
    "DB_LCYAMOUNT" NUMBER,
    "CR_FCYAMOUNT" NUMBER,
    "CR_LCYAMOUNT" NUMBER,
    "NET_FCY" NUMBER,
    "NET_LCY" NUMBER,
    "DSC" VARCHAR2(4000),
    "EMPE_CODE" VARCHAR2(100),
    "CIF" VARCHAR2(100),
    "LINE_SYSTEM_GL78" VARCHAR2(50),
    "LINE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "CUST_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20),
    "CUST_DIVISION" VARCHAR2(20),
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(50),
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(50),
    "TENOR" NUMBER,
    "CHANNEL" VARCHAR2(50),
    "SOURCE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "LV1_ID" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LV2_ID" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LV3_ID" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LV4_ID" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LV1_NAME" VARCHAR2(200),
    "LV2_NAME" VARCHAR2(200),
    "LV3_NAME" VARCHAR2(200),
    "LV4_NAME" VARCHAR2(200),
    "ITEM_1" VARCHAR2(50),
    "ITEM_2" VARCHAR2(50),
    "ITEM_3" VARCHAR2(50),
    "PRODUCT_LV1" VARCHAR2(11),
    "PRODUCT_LV2" VARCHAR2(200),
    "PRODUCT_LV3" VARCHAR2(200),
    "MONTHID" NUMBER
) PARTITION BY LIST (MONTHID) (
    PARTITION MONTHID_01 VALUES (202401),
    PARTITION MONTHID_02 VALUES (202402),
    PARTITION MONTHID_03 VALUES (202403),
    PARTITION MONTHID_04 VALUES (202404),
    PARTITION MONTHID_05 VALUES (202405),
    PARTITION MONTHID_06 VALUES (202406),
    PARTITION MONTHID_07 VALUES (202407)
);
---Index the MONTHID and TXN_DATE for Table A
CREATE INDEX txn_date_idx ON Table_A (MONTHID, TXN_DATE) LOCAL (
    PARTITION MONTHID_01,
    PARTITION MONTHID_02,
    PARTITION MONTHID_03,
    PARTITION MONTHID_04,
    PARTITION MONTHID_05,
    PARTITION MONTHID_06,
    PARTITION MONTHID_07
);
---Create table B 
Insert into Table_B  (select * from Table_A);
Create index IDX_MONTHID_TXNDATE on Table_B(MONTHID,TXN_DATE);


Then, I created a duplicate of this table, called table B, without partitions. Instead, I created a composite index on the MONTH_ID and DATE columns for B.
After comparing the execution plans of queries on both tables (the query i use to compare below), I found that queries on the non-partitioned table B are faster than on the partitioned table A. This was unexpected, as I assumed that partitioning a large table (along with indexing) would improve performance over a non-partitioned table.
Table B
Table A
SELECT GL_CODE, sum(NET_LCY) FROM Table_A
WHERE MONTHID = 202406 AND TXN_DATE = to_date('2024-06-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY GL_CODE





Operation
Object
Optimizer
Cost
Cardinality
Bytes




SELECT STATEMENT

ALL_ROWS
144,642
261
7,569


HASH GROUP BY

ALL_ROWS
144,642
261
7,569


PARTITION LIST (SINGLE)

ANALYZED
144,588
2,101,708
60,949,532


TABLE ACCESS (BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED)
Table_A
ANALYZED
144,588
2,101,708
60,949,532


INDEX RANGE SCAN
TXN_DATE_IDX
ANALYZED
5,591
2,101,899
0



SELECT GL_CODE, sum(NET_LCY) FROM Table_B
WHERE MONTHID = 202406 AND TXN_DATE = to_date('2024-06-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY GL_CODE




Operation
Object
Optimizer
Cost
Cardinality
Bytes




SELECT STATEMENT

ALL_ROWS
59,961
330
9,570


HASH GROUP BY

ANALYZED
59,961
330
9,570


TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED)
Table_B
ANALYZED
59,946
603,088
17,489,552


INDEX RANGE SCAN
Table_B MONTHID IDX
ANALYZED
3,123
603,088
0



Could someone explain why the non-partitioned table B performs better than the partitioned table A? Are there specific cases where partitioning might not provide the expected performance benefits, or is there something about my indexing or partitioning strategy that could be optimized?
Thank you for any insights!
Anyones suggest me that i have to index or partition with large table like this?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements for both tables; the EXPLAIN PLANs for both queries (as text, not images hidden behind links); and details of how you measured the performance for the two tables.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I just edited the post, thanks u guys

Are you just comparing the plan cost, or actually executing the query, several times and it is consistently slower on A than B?

The idea of 'partitioning' is to have faster sequential/table scan, you will make partitions for for each portion of  table which is too much for an 'index scan' too less for a 'sequential scan'. You will definitely get substantial gain if you querying or aggregating over a month's of data as it can now do a sequential scan with only subset of whole table.

Please be aware that optimizer cost is not the same as execution speed. You can only tell the performance difference when actually executing the queries, not by looking at the plan.

Partitioning does not improve query speed unless (1) your query prunes partitions by filtering on the partition key, and (2) your query is doing a full table scan to access the table. This is typical of a datawarehouse environment where queries crunch huge amounts of data. But in your example, you are using indexes in both scenarios, partitioning won't help performance.
In fact, it can actually hurt it. If you define an index on a partitioned table as LOCAL there are in fact many index segments, all separate b-tree structures. There is no overarching entry-point to these. So, if your query fails to prune partitions to a single partition, more than one index b-tree segment must be accessed and scanned. That means more work to find those rows. A global index on the other hand is a single index segment covering the whole table, so an index scan on it requires only one scan. So I would say it is quite typical for non-partitioned tables or partitioned tables with a global index to out-perform a partitioned table with local indexes if you are relying on those indexes. This is particularly acute for high cardinality indexes that support single-row lookups. For an index on a low cardinality column like TXN_DATE, the overhead of multiple scans is almost unnoticeable next to the amount of time for pulling table blocks.
Now, your precise example is a bit odd: you are in fact pruning partitions when you say MONTHID = 202406, so the locality of the index shouldn't be hurting you. I would say your two test queries should perform equally. When comparing, did you ensure that caching is not messing up your measurements? Are you sure they had the same data? Are you sure they were on the same tablespace? Did you check the wait interface to see if the wait profile was different? Did one have parallelism enabled and the other not? And I am assuming you actually ran these queries, and aren't simply relying on the costing from the execution plan (which is very frequently incorrect). Lots of things to check. But all other things being equal, your two test queries should perform identically.
My last comment is that with this partitioned table you are probably better off without any index on either the monthid or the txn_date field. Your queries should be pruning on monthid so that already narrows it down to one month - using an index to narrow that down to 1/30th is not as efficient as simply doing a full scan of the partition, especially if you enable parallel query. And definitely don't index monthid - if that's the partitioning key, it serves absolutely no purpose being indexed.
